# Are incoming webhooks available to all Google chat users or just users with Google Workspace access?

Tags: google-workspace, google-chat

I am currently a free user of Google chat, and I am trying to set up an incoming webhook to send myself asynchronous messages (notifications) in a chat space. I have not been able to locate the "Manage webhooks" dialog in the chat space menu. Is the incoming webhook chat bot feature for Google Chat only available for user with Google Workspace access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The documentaiton is not very clear about it, but to add a webhook, you should be able to create it first

The documentation for [Google Apps Script bot](https://developers.google.com/chat/quickstart/apps-script-bot) specifies:

> Prerequisites

> A Google Workspace account with access to Google Chat.

There is no direct respective mention for [Webhooks](https://developers.google.com/chat/quickstart/incoming-bot-node), but this seems to be a bug - see [There is no mention in the documentation of the "Configure webhooks" being available only for Workspace users](https://issuetracker.google.com/193885860).

In other words:

**Unfortunately, Incoming Webhooks are only available to Google Workspace users, even if it is currently not mentioned in the documentation.**

Comment: I have set up google workspace now, and I can see the "Manage webhooks" dialog in a chat space menu.